# My C++ code is not working (for class declaration)

Tags: c++, class, oop, forward-declaration

I am having problem in this code.
I have modified it a lot, but always the compiler shows an error of "Too many types in declaration", "Declaration ended incorrectly" and "Multiple declaration".
Please help me.
Note: This is just the beginning of the code. I could not post the full code because of the limitations.
If you want, I will send it to you...

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#define HR for(j=0;j<80;j++) cout<<"-";
#define SR for(j=0;j<80;j++) cout<<"=";
#define NEWLINE cout<<"\n";
class stud {friend class getrec;friend class sortrec;friend class list;friend class search;friend class edit;friend class delrec;}
class getrec{public:void f(class stud);};
class sortrec{public:void f(class stud);};
class list{public:void f(class stud);};
class search{public:void f(class stud);};
class edit{public:void f(class stud);};
class delrec{public:void f(class stud);};
struct student
{
    char name[20],sub[10];
    long roll,code;
    int internal,external;
}
class stud
{
    friend class getrec;
    friend class sortrec;
    friend class list;
    friend class search;
    friend class edit;
    friend class delrec;
    private:
        int choice,i,j,c,cur,b,rec;
        //char name[20];
        struct student e[96],t;
    public:
        stud()
        {
            for (c=0;c<96;c++)
            {
                e[i].internal=0;
                e[i].external=0;
                e[i].roll=-1;
                e[i].code=0;
                strcpy(e[i].name,"");
                strcpy(e[i].sub,"");
            }
        }
        int menu(void)
        {
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\tThe Database Management System of Employees"<<endl;
            cout<<"Choose any of these options by pressing any of their corresponding numbers"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. List he records."<<endl;
            cout<<"2. Delete old record."<<endl;
            cout<<"3. Insert new record."<<endl;
            cout<<"4. Edit record."<<endl;
            cout<<"5. Search for a record."<<endl;
            cout<<"6. Sort entries."<<endl;
            cout<<"7. Quit."<<endl;
            choice=getch();
            return choice;
        }
        ~stud()
        {
            clrscr();
            cout<<"The Database has been deleted.";
            getch();
        }
        void program(void)
        {
            do
            {
                menu();
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case '1':
                        list();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        delrec();
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        getrec();
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        edit();
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        search();
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        sortrec();
                        break;
                }
            } while (choice!='7');
        }
        void getrec(class getrec g)
        {
            g.f();
        }
        void sortrec(class sortrec s)
        {
            s.f();
        }
        void list(class list l)
        {
            l.f();
        }
        void search(class search s)
        {
            s.f();
        }
        void edit(class edit e)
        {
            e.f();
        }
        void delrec(class delrec d)
        {
            d.f();
        }
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ExJA.jpg)

Comment: Class definition needs a semicolon after the closing brace. As in `struct student { ... } ;`

Comment: Please post the *exact* compiler errors verbatim. Also please tell us exactly *what* compiler you are using (and what version) and also tell us on what platform you are compiling.

Comment: `class stud {friend class getrec;friend class sortrec;friend class list;friend class search;friend class edit;friend class delrec;}` is incorrect. Forward declaration doesn't need to specify any internal details. `class stud;` will be sufficient. Also strongly recommend upgrading your compiler from Turbo C++ to something less than 25 years old. Aim for 5-6 years behind, tops. Easier to find learning materials and more relevant when you find yourself working.

Comment: Present your [MCVE]. If you don't have one yet, you haven't finished your initial debugging.

Comment: Also Turbo C++ on DOS emulator, nice. Takes me back to, er, before I was born.

Comment: AG, when errors are allowed to travel in packs, they conceal one another. You have many errors in the code. This is part of the reason people are asking you to focus down on one with a [mcve].

Comment: My friend, We're asking you for the opposite. Reduce the complexity. When you have less noise in the system it is easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: Recommendation: `class getrec{public:void f(class stud);};` and its friends should probably either be `friend` functions or member functions. They maintain no state (have no variables), so they have no need to be classes.

Comment: Many thanks for all the inputs. I will work on them.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to specify `class` when declaring variables, function parameters or function return types.

Comment: You should develop a coding style to differentiate types (class names) versus variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow your class and struct declarations with a semicolon. It's there for declarations of variables of that type, and typedefs.

Comment: Haven't I put a semicolon?

Comment: No, not after the curly brackets for each class/struct.

Comment: e.g.:
`struct ab {int a; int b};`

Comment: Yeah, after class stud{}

Comment: But I tried forward declaration, it gives me an error

Comment: That's not the case in your source code. You also want to follow `struct student { ... }` with a semicolon too. Also forward declaration is simply `class stud;`, no body.

Comment: I edited struct student{} and class stud{}. But what about the other two errors?

Comment: Please avoid conversations in comments. If you want, take this to [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com).